# How do i make this jQuery animation reverse/toggle/play backwards on second click?

Tags: jquery, animation, click, toggle, margin

right now i have this

```
<script type='text/javascript'>

        $("#beau").click(function(){
        $("#beau").animate({"margin-Top": "738px"}, "fast");
        });

        </script>
```

and it works fine to drop the div down by changing "margin-Top" but what i want to do is when the user clicks it again it goes back up to a "margin-Top" of 700px and for it to repeat that over and over again. i think it's pretty simple but I've only be doing bits of jQuery for about 5 days :) so the heck if i know. but if you understand my question thank you for you're replies :).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`.toggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/):

```
$("#beau").toggle(function(){
    $(this).stop().animate({marginTop: 738}, "fast");
}, function() {
    $(this).stop().animate({marginTop: 700}, "fast");
});
```

I added a `stop()` just to make sure it doesn’t break the animation cycle if you click fast many times.

Comment: `.stop()` didn't fix that for me (I was using `slideUp()` and `slideDown()`, but the same principle applies here). Try `.stop(true,true)` instead - it immediately clears the animation queue and jumps to its end.